# jQuery Plugin Scoping Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, scope

Given the example below (click "content" on the right if you're using the jsfiddle link), why does `self` fall out of scope when it reaches the `clickHelper()`?

I can think of two ways to fix it... (1) I can pass it in as an argument, or (2) I can define `var self;` inside of the plugin (above `function clickHelper()`).

I don't want to do #1 though, because in my real implementation, I have a bunch of arguments already and a bunch of helper functions... I was hoping to use scope to avoid passing `self` around everywhere.

And I don't want to use #2 because it seems like if this plugin was used for multiple elements on the page, there could be race conditions... my assumption is that jQuery has 1 instance of the plugin, and therefore `var self` would only exist once.

I'm basically looking for the best practice of keeping `this` in scope inside of click event raised for a jQuery plugin.

**http://jsfiddle.net/QZc9v/**

```
<div id="a1">
    content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">=
    function info(n, s) {
        var id = (typeof (s.id) == "undefined") ? '' : ': ' + s.id;
        alert(n + ': ' + s + ': ' + typeof (s) + id);
    }

    (function ($) {    
        $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        function clickHelper() {
            info('self in the Helper...', self);
            self.innerHTML += '2';
        }
        function clickHandler() {
            var self = this;
            info('self in the Handler', self);
            self.innerHTML += '1';
            clickHelper();
        }
        this.bind('click', clickHandler);
        };
    }(jQuery));

    $(function () {
        $('#a1').myPlugin();
    });
</script>
```

**ETA:** #1 is probably the best bet if you don't mind the extra arguments, because #2 does race condition/thread safe issues as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QZc9v/2/) (click content 1, ok, and then content 2 really quick).  You can get away with #2 by defining your helper methods inside your handler method as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QZc9v/3/), which might work well for your if all your helper methods do is support your handler method.  And #3, I suppose, instead of calling JavaScript functions like you normally would `clickHelper()`, just use a proper closure `function(this) { var self = this; clickHelper() };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Guide on closures and scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)**

Variables are only available to the functions in which they are created. So by creating `self` inside of `clickHelper` you are making it a local variable only to the `clickHelpers` function.

By moving it into `myPlugins` scope its now accessible to the nested functions.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QZc9v/1/)**

```
 $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        var self = {}; // self declared here instead can be used within this scope now
        function clickHelper() {
            info('self in the Helper...', self);
            self.innerHTML += '2';
        }
        function clickHandler() {
            self = this;
            info('self in the Handler', self);
            self.innerHTML += '1';
            clickHelper();
        }
        this.bind('click', clickHandler);
    };
```

Comment: so that was #2 in my question.  when dealing with jQuery plugins, certainly `var self` in this case is not "thread safe"?

Comment: @Langdon heh, I should of read your whole question, I just noticed as well that it was under solution 2 you had proposed. I guess it depends on how your plugin works I would assume for the different elements passed it creates a new instance.

Comment: It's not thread safe... I used setTimeout to mimick an ajax request... http://jsfiddle.net/QZc9v/2/  If you click content 1 and then content 2 within a second... both "callbacks" will say "a2" was clicked.  I guess I **have** to pass self as an argument if I continue to use this "helper" methods.

Comment: +1 and accepted for the guide link.  I probably should have kept digging... writing the question did help give me better idea of what was going on though. :)

Comment: @Langdon Another possible way as well http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QZc9v/4/ to make it thread safe. Basically just returns a new function for each element passed, giving them all thier own scope.